# How do you show $XY$ has finite expectation?

Tags: probability, expectation

Let $X$ and $Y$ be a random variables with finite variance, so that expectation of $X^2$ is finite and so is expectation of $Y^2$

Comment: Using $|XY|\leqslant X^2+Y^2$, probably.

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, why is it true that $|XY|\leqslant X^2+Y^2$?

Comment: (|X| -|Y|)^2 is always greater or equal to zero :)  @Did

Comment: @user164945 Perfect.

Comment: Otherwise, Cauchy-Schwarz is also enough to conclude (upper bound by a product instead of a sum)

Answer (score 0):

By [Cauchy-Schwarz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Probability_theory):

$\mathbb{E}[XY]^2 \le \mathbb{E}[X^2]\mathbb{E}[Y^2]$